# jQuery Plugin - Passing Custom Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've built my own jQuery paging plugin. See below:

```
$.fn.extend({
    pager: function(options) {
        var settings = {
            pageSize: 10,
            onPageChanged: function() { }
        };

        if (options)
            $.extend(settings, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            // Trigger onPageChanged event
        });
    }
});
```

Which can be be called by saying:

```
$('#placeholder').pager({ pageSize: 20, onPageChanged: function() { alert('Page Changed!'); } });
```

I was wondering how to trigger the function passed in via the options within my plugin. I'm sure this is something simple but i can't seem to find anything in the documentation to help.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
settings.onPageChanged.call(this);
```

You can also optionally add additional arguments to `.call()` that will be passed to the function.

If you wanted a true custom event that could be bound to using   `$('#placeholder').on("onPageChanged",handler)` later on, do this instead:

```
this.on("onPageChanged",settings.onPageChanged);
```

and then trigger it with:

```
this.triggerHandler("onPageChanged");
```